# Simple Sort Sample for slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I want to havesimple slickgrid column sort. however I might not understand the basic idea.

what I have done is like this.

Make column sortable

```
{id: "score", name: "number", field: "score",sortable: true},
```

Make function for sort calculation.

```
function sortfn(o1, o2) {
  if (o1[column.field] > o2[column.field]) {
    return 1;
  } else if (o1[column.field] < o2[column.field]) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

then subsclibe to `onSort`.

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) { 
    grid.invalidateAllRows();
    grid.render();
  });
```

then next,,,,

I guess I should put `sortfn` somewhere though, but how??

where should I put `sortfn`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the examples [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples). There is no default sorting in the grid - this is left to the datasource to manage.

[This example](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-multi-column-sort.html) uses the native javascript `sort` property of the source data array to sort the rows:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  var cols = args.sortCols;

  data.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
    for (var i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
      var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
      var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
      var value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];
      var result = (value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
      if (result != 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  });
  grid.invalidate();
  grid.render();
});
```

[This example](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) outsources the sorting to the DataView object which is the grid's datasource.

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  sortdir = args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
  sortcol = args.sortCol.field;

  if (isIEPreVer9()) {
    // using temporary Object.prototype.toString override
    // more limited and does lexicographic sort only by default, but can be much faster

    var percentCompleteValueFn = function () {
      var val = this["percentComplete"];
      if (val < 10) {
        return "00" + val;
      } else if (val < 100) {
        return "0" + val;
      } else {
        return val;
      }
    };

    // use numeric sort of % and lexicographic for everything else
    dataView.fastSort((sortcol == "percentComplete") ? percentCompleteValueFn : sortcol, args.sortAsc);
  } else {
    // using native sort with comparer
    // preferred method but can be very slow in IE with huge datasets
    dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
  }
});
```

Comment: THank you very much!! The first example quite simple and good to start point. I could implement simple sort finally.

Answer (score 0):

I need to sort data consisting of numbers and letters, this has been working very well for me.

```js
function comparer(a, b) {
  var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: "base",
  });
  var x = a[sortcol];
  var y = b[sortcol];

  return collator.compare(x, y);
}

// add event listener to sort the grid
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
});
```